# cannot destructure property as it is undefined error

Tags: reactjs, shopping-cart, drawer, state-management, react-context

Creating an `onClick` event to open a cart drawer and receiving the error 'Cannot restructure property 'shoppingCartOpen' of 'value' as it is undefined'. How do I resolve it?

```
const ButtonAppBar = ({value}) => {
  const { shoppingCartOpen } = value
  let shoppingCartDrawer;
  if (this.state.shoppingCartOpen) {
    shoppingCartDrawer = <ShoppingCartDrawer />;
  }
```

Comment: Modify function parameters like this `(value)` and check the value you are getting. If it is null you cannot destruct like you are doing in the next line. If it is null you can return there itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't in this code snippet you've posted, it's in how you're calling it.  You're expecting `value` to be an object with the property `shoppingCartOpen`, so if `value` is `undefined`, then this line is a problem: `const { shoppingCartOpen } = value`.

You can default `value` to an empty object to supress errors

```
const ButtonAppBar = ({value = {}}) =>
```

But make sure that you are actually passing the right `value` to the props when you call it!  It should look like:

```
<ButtonAppBar value={someObject} />
```